# sum up count of row or sum of data in hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @orderTable TABLE
(
    orderNO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Qty NUMERIC(10,3),
    agentId int,
    parentid INT
)

INSERT INTO @orderTable (Qty, agentId, parentid )
VALUES (9, 1, 0),
       (2, 2, 1),
       (3, 3, 1)

SELECT * FROM @orderTable

orderNO Qty     agentId parentid
1       9.000   1       0
2       2.000   2       1
3       3.000   3       1
```

In the above table,I want to sum up the quantity based on the parent.And sum should have the parent order quantity also.

want to achieve this in a single query without using union.

Output:

```
parentId qty 
1        14
```

Comment: Show the expected output.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to sum the `Qty` grouped by `parentId` and also the `Qty` of the first record because `orderNO = parentId`? This looks like bad design.

Comment: no....agent -1 is the parent of 2 and 3 so

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT o.agentId as parentId,  t.childrenSum + SUM(Qty) OVER() AS qty
FROM @orderTable AS o
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(Qty) AS childrenSum
   FROM @orderTable
   WHERE parentid = o.agentId
) t
WHERE o.parentid = 0
```

produces this output:

```
parentId    qty
----------------
1           14.000
```

`WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE o.parentid = 0
```

presumably selects all **parent** records, whereas the `OUTER APPLY` sub-query calculates the quantity sum for all children of each of these **parents**.